# Subscribe to angular firestore collection with no need of real time updates

Tags: angularjs, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I subscribe to an angular firestore collection from my ionic app using valueChanges() function of AngularFirestoreCollection. However I do not need to get my data updated in real time. I **only** need the data which was present at the time of subscription. Is there a way achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just unsubscribe after you've got the data you need.

```
 let tempSubscription: Subscription = this.callReturningObservable(params)
              .subscribe(item => {
                tempSubscription.unsubscribe();
                tempSubscription = null;     // don't need this anymore
                this.storeTheItem = item;
              }, error => {
                console.error("Error: " + error.message);
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **subscribe()** use **toPromise().then(data => data)**. This fetches the data only once